# transformation matrix in an alternative basis and coordinates

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Hello I have a question.

I have 3 vectors $v_1, v_2, v_3$ in $R^3$ and I know that ($v_1, v_2, v_3$) is a basis for $R^3$

$$
  v_1, v_2, v_3 =     \begin{pmatrix}
        2 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & -1 & 1 \\
        0 & 0 & 3 \\
        \end{pmatrix} 
$$

Consinder the Linear Transformation: $f: R^3 \rightarrow R^3$, that's given by the matrix:

$$
    B=   \begin{pmatrix}
        2 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & -1 & 2 \\
        0 & 1 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix} 
$$
with regards to the basis ($v_1, v_2, v_3$) for the domain and codomain.

My Question is how do you find the matrix B?

I know that for x = (1,1,1), then f(x) = (2,1,2)
So I figured out that 
 $$
   f(x)= Bx =   \begin{pmatrix}
        2\cdot x_1 \\
         -x_2 + 2\cdot x_3\\
        x_2 + x_3 \\
        \end{pmatrix} 
$$
and I thought that Matrix B would be:
$$
  \begin{pmatrix}
        f(v_1) , f(v_2), f(v_3)  \\
         \end{pmatrix} 
$$
cause that's what I did previously when I was dealing with the standard basis.

Comment: You’ve got the right idea, but remember that $f(v_1)$ etc. have to be expressed relative to the output basis. It sounds like you’re writing them down in the standard basis.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. For $f(v_1)$ I got (4,0,0)?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to find? How to construct $B$ or how to convert it to the standard basis?

Comment: How to construct B. If I should convert it, I would just use the change of basis matrix, right?

Comment: So, how do you know what the linear transformation is in the first place? The only definition of it that you’ve provided is the matrix $B$, which as far as I can see, is given.

Comment: Well the questions in the exercise was to find the coordinates of the vector (f($v_1+v_2+v_3$)) in standard basis, and I did that, But I was wondering how I could construct B?

Comment: I wanted to know they said in the book, that it was important to remember the definition of the matrix, that represents the linear transformation with regards to the given basis for its domain and codomain, but I couldn't really understand it.